# CouchDB not recognising the update functions in my new design document

Tags: couchdb, design-documents

I have create a new design documents with a dummy update function. But when I try to test it, CouchDB is not identifying my function in the design document.

Below is my design document:

```
{
   "_id": "_design/payable_draft",
   "_rev": "13-c9c9a9f88c24b75cdd28204a526f66a6",
   "updates": "{\"empty_update\":\"function(doc, req){\n\treturn [doc,toJSON(\"empty_update\")];\n}\"}"
}
```

But when I try to invoke this update function using a put, getting 404.
Request:

```
PUT /db/_design/payable_draft/_update/empty_update/my_doc HTTP/1.1
Host: <my couchDB>
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

Response:

```
{
    "error": "not_found",
    "reason": "missing updates function empty_update on design doc _design/payable_draft"
}
```

I see everything looks fine, not able to find the issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your escaping is wrong. Your "updates" block contains one complete string. Try this one:

```
{  
  "_id":"_design/payable_draft",
  "_rev":"13-c9c9a9f88c24b75cdd28204a526f66a6",
  "updates":{  
     "empty_update" : "function(doc, req){return [doc,toJSON('empty_update')];}"
  }
}
```

See http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Document_Update_Handlers for more details. As described there one must place the update handler as attributes below "updates":

```
"updates" : {
    "myhandler" : "function(doc, req) { ... }"
}
```

Comment: You are right, I realised it while tweeking the functions hash. Thanks for the help!